# Bake-in logging statements of a Catch block

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

I'm working with a .Core 3.1 app that will have the conventional try/catch blocks --- all of them formed similar to:

```
Logger.LogWarning(ex, "Failed to load product {ProductId}",
```

There's going to be lots of these blocks -- logging the catch will be pretty much the same for all of them: A string message that will be unique per block plus the exception message.

So if every catch block is calling the logger, why is the explicit call required? What is the extension point to 'bake-in' the call to the logger and pass a log message to be established by convention.

So consider this code block:

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    var _logMessage = "OPSA calls GetProductByIdAsync with: " + ProductId;
    try
    {
        _loadFailed = false;
        _details = await GetProductByIdAsync(ProductId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _loadFailed = true;
        //app should implicitly call:
        // Logger.LogWarning(ex, _logMessage);
        // 
       // Shouldn't I expect to find a special something somewhere
       // to override the default behavior and inject that logger call?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Blazor? Client- or server-side? If you don’t want to catch the exception, would you want your component to continue working? How would it behave?

Comment: Code sample happens to be copied from a  Blazor clip. I'd still expect code to exist in the catch block to make for gracefully handling -- just feeling like the logger doesn't need to be included.

Comment: Well, if you handle an exception, then the usual expectation is that you handle it in a way that you can recover from it. And that makes the exception invisible to the outside. So it is impossible for the framework to detect it from the outside. As such you will have to log yourself if you determine that the exception is still noteworthy even after handling it.

Comment: A valid point but still, any exception, handled or not (ELMAH for the not) seems worth of logging.

Comment: Then it’s your job to do that. When _your_ method `GetProductByIdAsync` can throw an exception and _your_ code catches this exception, then it’s also _your_ job to log that exception because the framework literally has no way of figuring this out.